# Simple intuitive example as to why this proof technique is wrong

Tags: proof-writing

Suppose we want to prove the following:

`If f(x) has property A then f(x) also has property B`

I was told that if you prove `if f(x) has property B then f(x) also has property A`, this does not prove the original statement. Are there simple examples where one can see that this is the case?

Answer (score 0):

"If $x$ is a dog then $x$ is a mammal" is provable.  "If $x$ is a mammal then $x$ is a dog" is not, because of horses.  You cannot interchange $A$ and $B$ and expect the two statements to be equally provable.

Answer (score 0):

You can reverse the implication, but then you have to also negate both sides, e.g. $A \implies B$ is equivalent to $¬B \implies ¬A$. This is the contrapositive, and is sometimes easier to prove than $A \implies B$ directly.

When you want to prove $A \iff B$, then you must prove both $A \implies B$ and $B \implies A$. They are not the same thing.

A simple example could be for an integer $x > 2$, if $x$ is prime, then $x$ is odd. Clearly if $x$ is odd does not imply that $x$ is prime.

However, if $x$ is not odd does imply $x$ is not prime.